# How to copy an associative array inside another associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Can anyone tell me how to store an array of associative arrays?  I thought this code would work, but it's not.  I tried researching it but couldn't find an answer.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    // Some SQL...
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $row['NestedResults'][] = $row2;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row['NestedResults'] as $results) {
        echo $results['Item'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

PS: I know I shouldn't loop SQL statements like that, but it's a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `foreach` loop, you need to pass the `$row` variable by reference, otherwise you are just modifying a copy of the element from `$rows` stored in `$row`:

```
foreach($rows as &$row)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you think it is workable to put the second loop inside the first one as below?

`$row['NestedResults'][] = $row2;
    foreach ($row['NestedResults'] as $results) {
        echo $results['Item'] . '<br>';
    }`

not 100% sure...

Comment: I'm storing the results for HTML display later, so no, but thank you.